# Construct glob pattern based on date range in Python?

Tags: python, glob

Is there any existing Python library function (or otherwise reusable code) to construct a glob pattern based on a date range, or any other series of paths with common prefixes?

Here's the context: I have a lot of files organized into YYYY/MM/DD directories. I would like to load the files from the last 90 days. So as of today, that range would be from 2018/11/22 to 2019/02/20.

It's pretty easy to construct a glob pattern in Python that includes each individual day:

```
{2018/11/22,2018/11/23,2018/11/24,(and so on)}
```

But the resulting string will be quite long. If I were building the pattern by hand, it would look more like this:

```
{2018/{11/2[2-9],11/3*,12/*},2019/{01/*,02/[0-1]*,02/20}}
```

But building that programmatically is complicated, and I'd hate to find out after I've done it that there's a common library function that does it for you. Does anyone know if such a function exists already?

Comment: Why do you need a glob pattern?  what will be consuming these files?

Comment: We'll be passing the pattern as a command-line parameter to a Spark job that will consume the files and analyze them. Though a very long pattern may work fine, it will be easier to work with if it's shorter.

Comment: I'm in the same boat! Did your team come up with a solution that you can share? I'm about to take a stab at this but if you've already done it then maybe I can avoid re-inventing the wheel

Comment: @Jon.H we found that the simple solution `{2018/11/22,2018/11/23,2018/11/24,...}` worked for our use case, so we left it at that.